# KDB: Logic for determining daylight saving time?

Tags: date, datetime, time, kdb

I have a India datetime. Converting to Vancouver, BC, Canada time I get either 2:30 AM or 3:30 AM depending on whether or not it's daylight saving time. Is there a function I can use to apply daylight saving time logic?

Comment: What do you mean with function? There is a timezone file, which describe the rules. It is complex, because rules changes, and nobody know really sure if when next time there will be the change (ok, maybe the next yes, but not in few years)

Comment: Or rather, is there a way to convert from one local time to another local time in kdb and applying the rules of daylight saving time?

Answer (score 1):

There's a cookbook on the Kdb website on this subject but requires a comprehensive table of all the various time zones.

http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/timezones/#timezones-tz-and-daylight-savings-time-dst